# ssh linux to mac inside and outside lan

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

Hi this is my first post and I was wondering if anyone can help me? I have ubuntu on my home pc and I want to be able to ssh to a macbook. When they are both on the same wifi network it's no problem, but how do I ssh to the mac when it's outside the lan? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256467/want-to-ssh-to-a-server-behind-nat-from-a-host-also-behind-nat) earlier yesterday. Possible Duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the SSH server at home, but not away, then you might need to configure your router to allow SSH port-forwarding access. Note also that you are **not** accessing the remote Ubuntu machine by the local (usually 192.168.x.x) IP, but by the router's public IP address, which you can find by simply Googling "what is my ip" while on the home network.

Comment: How do I set that up? Also, what if I don't have access to the router?

Comment: First try accessing ssh from outside network without changing the router settings. Look up your public IP, then try typing in terminal
'ssh user@ip'
It probably won't go through without router port-forwarding, but worth a try first if you aren't comfortable with router config.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have to access the router, usually at 192.168.1.1 or similar. If you don't know the default username and password, they are usually on the manufacturer website. Port-forwarding setup is different for different routers, and I would recommend configuring it for an obscure port rather than 22 if you are already going to that much effort. Select a port number (you can find commonly used ports to avoid on Wikipedia), then on the Ubuntu edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to listen on that port. On the Macbook, when you login, add 'ssh user@ip -p port#

Answer (score 0):

Making an `ssh` connection from the Mac to the PC is fairly straightforward; you need either a static IP address or a dynamic dns name, and you need to forward tcp port 22 from the router to your PC's address (assuming you're on NAT here - if not, just allow the connection on your firewall).

Connecting to the Mac when it's off your network is considerably harder - you won't control the routers it'll be behind, so they won't forward the port.  There are a number of roll-your-own solutions that can overcome this, but they require quite a bit of network and scripting knowledge.  Your best bet is probably a VPN.

There are commercial products as well as free ones available, and your router might have built-in VPN support.  With a VPN, your laptop will effectively be on your network.  If you assign it a static IP on the VPN and set it to automatically connect to the VPN any time it is outside your network, you will be able to ssh to it from your desktop machine as long as it has an internet connection.

I can't really say more than that without knowing your network setup.